# How to use DropDownListFor in Html View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following class:

```
public class Regex
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string MessageExpression { get; set; }
    }
```

Another static class have a list of `Regex` called `RegexHelper`

In my View Im using that namespace so I can see the static list. Now I want to populate a dropdown list like this:

```
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(RegexHelper.listOfRegex, new SelectList(RegexHelper.listOfRegex, "Value", "Id",RegexHelper.listOfRegex.Select(p=> p.Id).First()));
                </div>
```

But it seems that `DropDownListFor` is not working, it is telling me that I have to specify the arguments Explicitly.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use DropDownList**For** as the first parameter references the field you want to set the value in.

DropDownList works fine though:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Regex", new SelectList(RegexHelper.ListOfRegex, "Value", "Id", RegexHelper.ListOfRegex.Select(p => p.Id).First()))
```

If you have a controller with a model e.g. TestResult

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{       
    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        return View(new TestResult());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Foo(TestResult t)
    {
        return View(t);
    }
}

public class TestResult
{
    public string SelectedRegex { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can set it with DropDownListFor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRegex, new SelectList(RegexHelper.ListOfRegex, "Value", "Id", RegexHelper.ListOfRegex.Select(p => p.Id).First()))    
            </div>

}
```